# Using service methods for feathers-sequelize (Unexpected token < in JSON)

Tags: json, postgresql, sequelize.js, feathersjs

It looks like I am missing something in my setup. I'm getting a vague and general error as I attempt to retrieve a resource with

`api.service('listings').find()`

The same counts for finding users

The error is:

> Unexpected token < in JSON

I can't find out whether somewhere I'm not parsing or whether the service methods themselves are not available yet. Starting the server with `DEBUG=feathers* npm start` doesn't give me much clues. I am able to login and receive post requests using curl though. What am I missing?

This is part of my Api class:

```
class API {
  constructor() {
    this.app = feathers()
      .configure(feathers.hooks())
      .configure(feathers.rest().fetch(fetch))
  }

  service(serviceName) {
    return this.app.service(serviceName)
  }
```

This is part of my app.js:

```
app.use(compress())
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Are the service methods always available after scaffolding a REST app? For the apps where I used sockets they were instantly available I believe. Does fetch (or something similar) do this for me? Or should I define everything myself e.g. like so:

```
const service = require('feathers-sequelize')

const myService = {
  find(params [, callback]) {},
  get(id, params [, callback]) {},
  create(data, params [, callback]) {},
  update(id, data, params [, callback]) {},
  patch(id, data, params [, callback]) {},
  remove(id, params [, callback]) {},
  setup(app, path) {}
}

app.use('/listings', myService)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you inspect the network tab and see what you get back for the request to `/listings`? It is probably some error HTML that's coming back from the browser.

Comment: I have a broken app cause I'm struggling with sequelize at the same time :/ Will come back to this later if that's okay.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://imgur.com/2EtEEM9)?
Or maybe [this](http://imgur.com/RhfgXp5)?

Comment: I see in my terminal that the find event is not dispatched.

Even though I read: `feathers:application Setting up service for 'listings'`

Comment: Yes but if you register another handler for that route (which it looks like you did, to return your `index.html`) before the service - just like any other Express middleware - the service will never run.

Comment: I was doing `.get('*', function(req, res) {
    sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'))
  })` before I was configuring servieces and middleware with `.configure(services)` and `.configure(middleware)`. That's not right. The order should be reversed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was doing

```
.get('*', function(req, res) { 
  sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html')) 
})
```

before I was configuring services and middleware with `.configure(services)` and `.configure(middleware)`. That's not right. The order should be reversed.